# Set two objects in a single window - VTK

Tags: visual-c++, vtk

I have to show two surfaces in the same vtk window. I have done this using the example

> http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/MoveActor

Though I am getting the surfaces, their coordinated are diffrent. Can someone explain me why? (I did not set a center there.) The problem in detail is explained in the vtk mailing list.

> http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Set-two-objects-in-a-single-window-VTK-td5471394.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand this question on the mailing list either. If the coordinates are different, of course they will show up in different positions...